# Carrierwave and mini_magick finding widths & height

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, ruby-on-rails-3

After a bit of investigation I decided to use Carrierwave and mini_magick on my new rail3 app.

I've set it up and it works perfectly.  However I have a one question. I'd like to be able to access the width and height, so I can form the html correctly.  However, there is no default data from which to get this information. Because of the way it stores the data I'm I cannot think of any way that I can add it to the database.

Can anyone suggest any tips or ideas?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
class Attachment
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader

  def image
    @image ||= MiniMagick::Image.open(file.path)
  end
end
```

And use it like this:

```
Attachment.first.image['width'] # => 400
Attachment.first.image['height'] # => 300
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for record, I have used a similar solution, however using files with Mongo GridFS, here it goes:

```
  def image
    @image ||= MiniMagick::Image.read(Mongo::GridFileSystem.new(Mongoid.database).open(file.path, 'r'))
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disadvantage** of calculating Image `height` / `width` using `RMagick` or `MiniMagick` in run time:

- Its CPU intensive
- It requires Internet to get image and calculate the dimensions.
- Its a slow process

> FYI   You can also calculate the Image `Height`, `Width` after the
>   Image is fully loaded by using the `load` event associated with the
>   `<img>` tag with the help of jQuery.

**For Example**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   var $image = $('.fixed-frame img');
   $image.load(function(){
      rePositionLogo($image);
   });

  if($image.prop('complete')){
    rePositionLogo($image);
  }

});

function rePositionLogo($image){
  var height = $image.height();
  var width = $image.width();
  if (width > height) {
    $image.parents('.header').addClass('landscape');
    var marginTop = (105 - $image.height())/2;
    $image.css('margin-top', marginTop + 'px')
  }else{
    $image.parents('.header').addClass('portrait');
  }
}
```

Be careful, because `load()` will not trigger when an image is already loaded. This can happens easily when an image is in the user's browser `cache`.

You can check if an image is already loaded using `$('#myImage').prop('complete')`, which returns `true` when an image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to store the image dimensions in the model (database).

In my case, the model name is `attachment`. Then I created a migration:

```
rails g migration add_dimensions_to_attachments image_width:integer image_height:integer
```

After that, run the migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

In my Image Uploader file `app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb`, I have:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    process :store_dimensions

    private

    def store_dimensions
      if file && model
        model.image_width, model.image_height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
      end
    end
  end
```

With this, the image dimensions is saved in the upload step.

To get the dimensions, I simply run `attachment.image_width` or `attachment.image_height`

See the [reference here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-image-dimensions).