# Ruby on Rails - Carrierwave get the image dimension width and height

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle, carrierwave

I need to know the width and height of the current instance of carrierwave

For example:

```
image_tag image.photo_url,:width => image.photo.width, :height => image.photo.height
```

But the problem is that image.photo.width and image.photo.height are not working.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Agreed; you can't expect help here if you don't accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install ImageMagick, RMagick or MiniMagick. Then you open the file (image) before you can find out its height.

Example: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#conditional-versions (see the is_landscape? method), copied here:

```
  def is_landscape? picture
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(picture.path)
    image[:width] > image[:height]
  end
```

Or this other related question:

[Carrierwave and mini_magick finding widths & height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454223/carrierwave-and-mini-magick-finding-widths-height)

Comment: "No such file or directory" this is what I get when I try to open picture.path.

Comment: You can return the height/width from a model method (which opens the file to check the width/height), and call the method from your view. Check that picture.path contains the correct file path (puts or debugger), and check your pwd (present working directory)

Comment: Yes I already tried it. Even MiniMagick::Image.open("/uploads/avatar/avatar/269/naruto.jpg") doesn't work.. weird

Comment: The other possibility is that you might not have the permissions. Check that the user running the Rails server can access the image. If not, try chown or chmod to give permission. Perhaps you added the image using your admin account instead of the webserver account.

Comment: I have used "chmod 777" on my file but still "No such file or directory"

Comment: here is the solution, need to add "public" MiniMagick::Image.open("public/uploads/avatar/avatar/269/naruto.jpg")