# How to get image height and width using CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, image-processing

I'm new to Rails. I try to create an app for working with images. It should do some actions depending on image size.

I use `CarrierWave` as uploader and after uploading I need to get the image `width` and `height` and save it in a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-image-dimensions  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022653/ruby-on-rails-carrierwave-get-the-image-dimension-width-and-height

Comment: Please, post some code, more examples.

Answer (score 3):

Lets say you are using `MiniMagick::Image` in `uploader`

in your model define a method: -
lets say:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  def get_image_height_and_width
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(avatar.path)
    return [image[:width],image[:height]]
  end
end
```

you can call this on your object example: -

```
MyModel.find(#id_of_field).get_image_height_and_width
=> [100px,200px] #will return array to width and height
```